# Actionscript 3 I need someon to help me with Collision Detecting(hiTestObject)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, collision-detection

I will try to explain the issue as good as possible.
What I want to do is to check for collision between to objects. Also the bullet and the enemy, if it was 1 of the bullet and 1 of the enemy it would be no problem, but after one day on google and tryed like every solutions I can't get it to work, or I find a solution that's absolutely terrible explained. 
Im going to make it easyer. I have MainClass.as that document class. 
It's one class for the Enemy and one for the Bullet. As I hope everyone understand I wan't to check if the bullet hit's the Enemy. Or the other way. Since the bullet's are been made while clicking for example it is not possible to direct refere to the bullet. What I have tryed is using sprite container, it does work if i place the bullet on the enemy just to check, but if I place one under and on over that's NOT hit the Enemy it's still says that the enemy got hit. 
Note, the Enemy are dragged on stage, since im going to have multiple of them. I could also add them with code.  Ive tryed to use Array to shuffle between all the enemys but I can't get it to work.

I know this was much text. Hope someon are willing to help me out, it is so frustrating...

Best regards HFherasen!:):)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you don't use a physics engine, like Box2DFlash, it can be frustrating.

First, you have to know the speed/frame of the bullet, because if it goes beyond the target in one frame, simple detection won't work.
Than, you should have a velocity and direction of the bullet.. For simplicity, lets use one point of it. (the head of the bullet, or the middle)
The bullet usually moves a lot faster than the targets, so you can assume the targets fixed.
The target is a rectangle, or polygon possibly rotated.

Now you have a target, and a line for the bullet (from the point and direction).
http://keith-hair.net/blog/2008/08/04/find-intersection-point-of-two-lines-in-as3/
You can use this (converted to as3), with all sides of the target (or only the ones facing to a bullet), and if one matches, the shot will hit a target. 
If your bullet is slower, you can have the position change of the frames as your first line. Than you'll know, when it hits a target.  This is pretty fast, and works well. Hope it helped.

Comment: Thank's as you say it is no easy way out. 
But while you mention physics engine, maybe I should check it out. 
I checked the link and it looks like a very good solution, but it was kind of advanced at the same time. Will I be able to do this with a physic engine?:)
And again, thank's for answering my question!!:D

Comment: yes, of couse! plus, in physics engine, you can have masses as well, and for example, the bullet can push back the target a bit. But beware, box2d looks pretty hard for first time, it takes 1-2 days to learn, and understand. After that it will save you a lot of time. at http://www.box2dflash.org/ you have source code and examples, but I recommend going to http://www.emanueleferonato.com/ as he has a lots of great tutorials (and also a book) about box2d. If you want to use GPU acceleration (Starling), I recommend citrus framework. Tutorial at: http://www.gotoandlearn.com/play.php?id=171

Comment: (you can add collision detection to box2d as eventlisteners, and if you define the target as not movable, it won't move after collision. I don't know your app, but if its a view from above, you may have to set gravity to 0. otherwise the objects will fall down..

Comment: Yeah Ive looked on the box2d and it does look relative hard, But when I get the time Im going to check it out:) So thank's for the help! I also see that Nape looks  good, have you tryed it :)?

Comment: No, I've only experimented with box2d, for two reasons: it is the most popular in the community, so there are lots of tutorials and help, and it is adapted from a c++ library (box2d), so its memory handling is as good as in c++